# Why my Toast Not Displaying

Tags: android, android-toast

In the following code, my toast is not displayed. However, I get the error, "RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".
I tried `Add_City.this` and `getApplicationContext`

```
try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                code=(json_data.getInt("code"));
                System.out.println(code);
                if(code==1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_City.this, "Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_City.this, "Sorry, City Already Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Log.i("TAG", "Result Retrieved");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAG", e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: May be have a exception when you open a stream or parser json

Comment: Is System.out.println(code); getting printed in your console. If not, the your execution is never reaching that piece of code. Check if Log.i("TAG", e.toString()); is getting logged in console. If so, you have an exception. Resolve the exception and you should get your toast.

Comment: To print the code  in console i am getting {"code":"0"} @Tony

Comment: Is Log.i("TAG", e.toString()); printing something in the android monitor? If so what is it?

Comment: Is Add_City the current activity?

Comment: yes Add_City is current activity and Log.i("TAG", e.toString()); printing like 105 @Tony

Comment: use e.printStackTrace(); statement in catch statement and you will have whole stacktrace that can help u solve issue.

Comment: also getting this one java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting,

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

I believe you are calling your toast inside a worker thread. For example, the doInBackground() of AsyncTask. Toast should only be called in the UI thread.

Try this,

```
new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer[] params) {
            int code = 1; //your logic here.
            return code;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer code) {
            super.onPostExecute(code);
            if(code==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Add_City.this, "Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Add_City.this, "Sorry, City Already Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: @AndroidBoy, Please accept the above answer if you find it satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Either you are getting some exception or the code for showing the toast is not being executing on the main thread.

Try using this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            //Your toast here
 Toast.makeText(Add_City.this, "Sorry, City Already Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i prevent?